# Black and white Checkerboard in XRDP

Tags: gnome, rdp, xrdp, x11rdp

I've recently been trying to install and connect to xrdp in Ubuntu 13.10, and authentication seems to be going properly, but when the screen transitions to the OS, the only thing I can see is a checkerboard. There's no menus or other indicators that Ubuntu even boots(though I know it does, I can ssh to it). When I run xrdp -nodaemon I get these errors:

```
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: connect failed trying again...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: connect failed trying again...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: connect failed trying again...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: connect failed trying again...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: error in trans_connect chan
```

It may also be useful to know that I'm not currently using a monitor in this system.